# Undocumented format of Linux Audit log records

Tags: linux, security, logs, audit, linux-audit

I am writing a parser for Linux Audit and I stumbled upon some weird cases which doesn't seem to comply with the standard.

My reference is the [Red Hat's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Understanding_Audit_Log_Files.html).

A proper audit record should look like this:

> ```
> type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1464013671.517:403): pid=3569 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=7 msg='cwd="/root" cmd=123 terminal=pts/1 res=success'
> ```

## An invalid name=value field in a record

Let's look at the following record:

> ```
> type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1464013652.147:626): auditd start, ver=2.4 format=raw kernel=3.16.0-4-586 auid=4294967295 pid=3557 res=success
> ```

The documentation says nothing about `auditd start` which doesn't fit the **name=value** format.

What is this? Where I can read about it?

## A comma and a space as a separator

Additionally, the documentation says that

> Each record consists of several name=value pairs separated by a white space or a comma.

It is clearly not true since we can see that `auditd start, ver=2.4` are separated with a command *and* a space.

Why is it so? Where is the standard *really* described?

## Additional whitespaces in a record

Let's look at the following record:

```
type=CWD msg=audit(1464013682.961:409):  cwd="/root"
```

It has two spaces between `type=CWD msg=audit(1464013682.961:409):` and `cwd="/root"`. It doesn't make any sense. In fact, I observed this behaviour only in records with `type=CWD` and `cwd="/root"`.

Why is it so?

---

*Note: I've generated those logs on a recent Debian.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved tiny a part of the problem - I found out that `auditd start, ver=2.2` is valid. I failed to find any documentation though. The only document I have is an example from the Red Hat's manual:

> Example 7.5. Additional audit.log events
>
> The following Audit event records a successful start of the auditd daemon. The ver field shows the version of the Audit daemon that was started.
>
> ```
> type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1363713609.192:5426): auditd start, ver=2.2 format=raw kernel=2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 auid=500 pid=4979 subj=unconfined_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=success
> ```
>
> The following Audit event records a failed attempt of user with UID of 500 to log in as the root user.
>
> ```
> type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1364475353.159:24270): user pid=3280 uid=500 auid=500 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" exe="/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=failed'
> ```

The sad thing is that these are only examples. I'd love to read the actual documentation of the standard since I cannot find it anywhere.

---

## Update

I asked those questions of the official mailing list ([see the full reply to my question](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-July/msg00067.html)).

Here's what I've learnt:

### An invalid name=value field in a record

I isn't clear to me why `auditd start` exist but here's the Steve Grubb's answer to my question.

> > Where are all the elements like auditd start, user, etc. listed? I cannot find any document which specifies what can occurs between the
> >     colon (separating the type and the msg=audit(…) from the fields) and
> >     the record’s fields.
>
> There really is none, Libauparse takes care of all of this so that you
>   don't  have to. If you are wanting to do translation, you can feed the
>   logs into  auparse and then just format the event the way you want.

Basically, the answer is hidden somewhere in the auparse library.

### A comma and a space as a separator

> > Why do some records are separated by a comma and a whitespace?
> >     Example:
> >
> > ```
> > type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1363713609.192:5426): auditd start, ver=2.2 format=raw kernel=2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 auid=500 pid=4979 subj=unconfined_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=success
> > ```
>
> A long time ago the records were meant to be both human readable
>   (don't laugh)  and machine consumable. Over time these have been
>   converted name=value pairs.  Even the one you mention above has been
>   fixed.

#### Additional whitespaces in a record

This one has already been patched by Steve Grubb.

The patch: https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-July/msg00086.html